# A finite product of nilpotent groups is nilpotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, nilpotent-groups

**Definition 1:**

> Let $G$ be a group. The **lower central series** of $G$ is the sequence
>   $\big(C^n(G)\big)_{n\ge 1}$ of subgroups of $G$ defined inductively
>   by: $C^1(G)=G$ and $$C^{n+1}(G)=[G,C^n(G)],$$ where $[G,C^n(G)]$
>   denotes the subgroup generated by the commutators $[g,g']$ with $g\in
>  G$ and $g'\in C^n(G)$.

**Definition 2:**

> A group $G$ is called **nilpotent** if there exists an integer $n$ such
>   that $C^{n+1}(G)=\{e\}$. The least integer $n$ such that
>   $C^{n+1}(G)=\{e\}$ is called the **nilpotency class** of a nilpotent group
>   $G$.

Now, let $(G_i)_{1\leq i\leq p}$ be a finite sequence of nilpotent groups. I have to show that the group
$$\prod_{i=1}^p G_i$$
is also nilpotent.

**Attempt:** (not much of an attempt)

Let $(n_i)_{1\leq i\leq p}$ be the sequence of the nilpotency classes of the family $(G_i)_{1\leq i\leq p}$: i.e. $n_i\in\mathbb{N}$ is the least integer such that

$$C^{n_i+1}(G_i)=\{e_i\}.$$

I have to find a $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $C^{k+1}(\prod_{i=1}^pG_i)=\{(e_i)_{1\leq i\leq p}\}$.

I have no idea where to start or what strategy to employ. I only know that somehow I have to use the sequence of nilpotency classes $(n_i)_{1\leq i\leq p}$. Any hints?

Comment: Hint: $Z(A\times B) = Z(A)\times Z(B)$, and $[A\times B,A\times B] = [A,A]\times[B,B]$.